# How can I move tooltip on top of the mouse pointer?

Tags: javascript, html, css

```js
let screenLog = document.querySelector('#screen-log');
        document.addEventListener('mousemove', logKey);

    var imgHgt = document.getElementById('box');

function logKey(e) {
    var d = document.getElementById('TextHidden');
  d.style.position = "absolute";
  d.style.left = e.clientX +'px';
  d.style.top = e.clientY +'px';

  screenLog.innerHTML = `${e.clientX}, ${e.clientY}` + "<br>Image Height = " + imgHgt.offsetHeight + "<br>Image Width = " + imgHgt.offsetWidth;
}
```

```css
#box { width: 40%; display: block; position: absolute; overflow: hidden; }
.image { display: block; width: 100%; z-index: 1; }
#TextHidden { display: none; color: red; font-size;  20px; z-index: 10; } #box:hover #TextHidden { display: block; }
#screen-log { z-index: 11; }
```

```html
<div id="box"> 
  <img src="https://res.cloudinary.com/vaqar/image/upload/v1499826226/DSC_0361_y3mv4r.jpg" class="image"></p> </img>
  <div id="TextHidden">Hovering<p id="screen-log"></p></div>
 </div>
```

I am trying to move comments on top of the the mouse pointer, but having no success.

Comment: I think a better word for what you're trying to make is 'tooltip' rather than 'comments'. Maybe update the question to reflect this?

Comment: Could you provide a picture of what `move comments on top of the mouse pointer` means?

Comment: @Richard, I have added the code snippet.

Comment: Thank you, that's really helpful, but it doesn't clarify what `move comments on top of the mouse pointer` mean. Do you want the mouse pointer to disappear and instead be replaced by the text? Or do you want to move the text position slightly upwards?

Comment: Yes I want a the text should be positioned upside the mouse pointer, but want the mouse pointer remains under the text.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your approach is working in principle, but you don't see the moving text because it is currently hidden. Note that I commented out the `overflow: hidden` and `display: none` properties in your stylesheet.

```js
let screenLog = document.querySelector('#screen-log');
document.addEventListener('mousemove', logKey);

var imgHgt = document.getElementById('box');

function logKey(e) {
  var d = document.getElementById('TextHidden');
  d.style.position = "absolute";
  d.style.left = e.clientX + 'px';
  d.style.top = e.clientY + 'px';

  screenLog.innerHTML = `${e.clientX}, ${e.clientY}` + "<br>Image Height = " + imgHgt.offsetHeight + "<br>Image Width = " + imgHgt.offsetWidth;
}
```

```css
#box {
  width: 40%;
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  #overflow: hidden;
}

.image {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  z-index: 1;
}

#TextHidden {
  #display: none;
  color: red;
  font-size: 20px;
  z-index: 10;
}

#box:hover #TextHidden {
  display: block;
}

#screen-log {
  z-index: 11;
}
```

```html
<div id="box">
  <div id="TextHidden">
    <p id="screen-log"></p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I am trying to move the comments/tooltip above the mouse pointer. The reason I put the overflow: hidden; is to bind the comments inside the picture. The box is displaced  only when the pointer hovers the picture.

Answer (score 1):

Change your `left` and `top` position pixels like,

```
  d.style.left = (e.clientX - 50) +'px';
  d.style.top = (e.clientY - 100) +'px';
```

And the snippet as follows,

```js
let screenLog = document.querySelector('#screen-log');
        document.addEventListener('mousemove', logKey);

    var imgHgt = document.getElementById('box');

function logKey(e) {
    var d = document.getElementById('TextHidden');
  d.style.position = "absolute";
  d.style.left = (e.clientX - 50) +'px';
  d.style.top = (e.clientY - 100) +'px';

  screenLog.innerHTML = `${e.clientX}, ${e.clientY}` + "<br>Image Height = " + imgHgt.offsetHeight + "<br>Image Width = " + imgHgt.offsetWidth;
}
```

```css
#box { width: 40%; display: block; position: absolute; overflow: hidden; }
.image { display: block; width: 100%; z-index: 1; }
#TextHidden { display: none; color: red; font-size;  20px; z-index: 10; } #box:hover #TextHidden { display: block; }
#screen-log { z-index: 11; }
```

```html
<div id="box"> 
  <img src="https://res.cloudinary.com/vaqar/image/upload/v1499826226/DSC_0361_y3mv4r.jpg" class="image"></p> </img>
  <div id="TextHidden">Hovering<p id="screen-log"></p></div>
 </div>
```